# Bootstrap date picker throws an error once date value is selected?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have implemented bootstrap date picker in my project. Here is example of my code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({});
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="beg_dt" id="beg_dt" value="" size="10">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why date-picker doesn't work. I need to set the width of the input field as well. The attribute size is included, but the width is not correct. Instead of being equal to size 10 the width is going through entire screen. If anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your `script` file in `head` tag. `jQuery-UI.js` should be above `bootstrap-datepicker.js`.

Here is the working snippet for the same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="beg_dt" id="beg_dt" value="" size="10">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```